# Any simple alternative to default_if_none that can also handle '0' value?

Tags: python, django

I am running the following command to filter out empty values in my template:

{{ product.error_value1|default_if_none:"--" }}

This works well for Null Values but doesn't work if the value entered is "0".  I wish the command 'default_if_null' existed.  This way it would only check for null.

Any suggestions on an alternative?

Comment: It's trivial to write your own template filters in Django, so just add one.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If what you mean is you want things like "", [], 0, {}, etc to return True, you can use:

```py
if not bool(x):
```

Or just simply:

```py
if not x:
```